# Android Kernel: new CPU governor

Tags: android, android-kernel

I'm trying to make a new CPU governor, which it verifies threads has each core and it gives more frequency to the one who has more threads in that moment and less threads to that core in the next program request.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried to find something on google, but nothing worth much...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look into the kernel code of the device you're working on.
The governors are located in /drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_.c

You can take example from the other governors located in that dir.